# Connection to website interrupted/reset. Why?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet, dns

When navigating to some websites (like victorsosea.com, citibank.co.in etc.) on Google Chrome, I get a message that the 'connection to www.site.com was interrupted'. If I try on Firefox, it says 'The connection to the server was reset'.

This happens no matter what internet connection I use on my laptop. Be it my home internet or office internet.

I have tried using Google DNS address as well but that does not seem to solve the problem. I have been facing this problem randomly for some websites. Kindly let me know how I can resolve the issue.

My laptop configuration: Windows 7, 64-bit

Comment: Same computer? Different computer? You didn't mention if you're using a laptop or multiple PCs. Also, what OS? Mac, Windows XP, Windows 7, Vista, Linux?

Comment: It may be a problem with your network card, either hardware failure or you may just need to update your drivers.

Comment: Hi jmort253, I have edited my question as per your comment. I use the same laptop at home and also at office.

Answer (score 2):

Did you find any computer from which it works? Because actually the reason for this message is that the **DNS query** for the domain **fails**. No IP address is currently assigned to the name vectorsea.com (or www.vectorsea.com).

Comment: The message should be "server not found" or "cannot find" for `vectorsea.com`

Comment: Sorry @zpea.. I mentioned wrong domain. It's actually victorsosea.com. I was able to browse this some days back. But suddenly Chrome started giving the interrupted error for it couple of days back.

Comment: @iglvzx Damn, you are right. Did not pay attention to the message, after `dig` confirmed there was no entry.

Comment: Ok, great, this one and citibank.co.in have DNS entries.